# Creating custom animation in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new to React-native but it seems so cool! I am trying to create animation like this: there is a  centered dot in the middle of a screen and after 1s the dot starts to stretch outwards (towards screen border) creating a line. I was looking for such animation in Animatable and Animated but couldn't find anything similar.
Does anyone could help me?

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly to spec, but should get you started:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    width: new Animated.Value(5),
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.width,
      {
        toValue: 500,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: Easing.linear,
      }).start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', width:     this.state.width, height: 5}}>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! It really helped. What if i wanted the line to stretch e.g only in one direction?(right or left)

Comment: Read up on how to position views absolutely and use the animated values for left: width: etc.